# Azure DevOps Diff Syntax Highlighting

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

We use Oracle for our databases so have a lot of .pak and .bod files in our Azure Repo.

Currently, when you create a pull request the diff view will show it with no syntax highlighting. I'm trying to get ADO to treat them as .sql files as they are essentially the same and that is how we used to be able to see the syntax on gitlab.

Is there any way to do this on ADO?